# ActivityNotFound

Tags: android

When I put my apk into `/data/app` (use `eclipes` default setting), I can correctly open it with `adb` shell command

```
adb shell am start -n com.ics.mm/com.ics.mm.MM_demoActivity
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings }
```

But when I push it into `/system/app`, I cannot find it.

```
adb shell am start -n com.ics.mm/com.ics.mm.MM_demoActivity
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.ics.mm/.MM_demoActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.ics.mm/com.ics.mm.MM_demoActivity} does not exist.
```

I use jni in my project.Does it concern?

Comment: Is this a rooted device?

Comment: Have you declared that activity in manifest.xml file?

Comment: you mean I should add special part in manifest.xml when i push it into  /system/app? i'v declared normally, so i can start it in the first coddition above.

Comment: You must to declare the activity in manifest. like  <activity
            android:name="com.example.xya"></activity>

Answer (score 0):

I'v solved it.

This is because my project use JNI and there're two *.so libraries in libs/armeabi.

when I install the apk by eclipse or use "adb install" command, the libs will be installed to /data/data/"your_package_name"/lib automatically.

but if you want to push apk into /system/apk folder using "adb push", you must push two *.so libs into /system/lib folder manual.

that's all, thank you, every friend.